# Powershell - Check if specific modules are installed and take action if not installed

Tags: powershell

new to stackoverflow and novice at Powershell, so go easy.

I'm looking for a way for a Powershell script to check if specific modules are installed.  If not then give a message asking if they would like to install those not installed.  If all are installed then proceed with the script.

I've seen the '#requires -Module' option but I want to provide a better prompt rather than the Powershell red text.

For reference, I want to check if AzureAD, ExchangeOnlineManagement, and MSOnline modules are installed

Any help appreciated.

Regards,
Lee

Answer (score 3):

To offer an alternative to [Steven's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72840280/45375) that handles the missing modules *as a group* :

```bash
# Define all required modules
$modules = 'AzureAD', 'ExchangeOnlineManagement', 'MSOnline'

# Find those that are already installed.
$installed = @((Get-Module $modules -ListAvailable).Name | Select-Object -Unique)

# Infer which ones *aren't* installed.
$notInstalled = Compare-Object $modules $installed -PassThru

if ($notInstalled) { # At least one module is missing.

  # Prompt for installing the missing ones.
  $promptText = @"
  The following modules aren't currently installed:
  
      $notInstalled
  
  Would you like to install them now?
"@
  $choice = $host.UI.PromptForChoice('Missing modules', $promptText, ('&Yes', '&No'), 0)
  
  if ($choice -ne 0) { Write-Warning 'Aborted.'; exit 1 }
  
  # Install the missing modules now.
  # Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser $notInstalled
}
```

Comment: @Doug, I can only tell you my personal view on this: if the question is well-formulated, focused enough, and of general interest, I think it is worth answering even if it shows no solution effort. Of course, showing one's attempt is always preferable.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your view on it. As always, you are amazing!

Comment: @mklement0.. thank you for this.. this is perfect.

This is exactly what I had in my head that I wanted to achieve but I just couldn't figure out the correct way of getting there.  As I said in the post, a complete novice when it comes to Powershell, with some very basic knowledge so the above helped massively and is building up my skills.

Very much appreciated

Comment: Glad to hear it, @LeeGee82; my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

As alluded to in your question, there are a few ways to ensure modules are available to a script or module.  Modules can define other modules as well as other prerequisites.  `#Requires` can be used, but neither facility will prompt or otherwise install a module.  Instead, they will prevent the loading or running of the dependent script etc.

If you want to start building a function you can check if a module is available on the given system with:

```
Get-Module -Name <ModuleName> -ListAvailable
```

You can wrap this in a loop with an `If` block to cover multiple modules:

```
ForEach( $Module in $RequiredModules ) 
{
    If ( !(Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name $Module) ) {
        # find, install and load the module.
    }
}
```

I would draw your attention to the other *Module cmdlets to build out the remaining functionality you described.

[Find-Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/find-module?view=powershell-7.2)

[Install-Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershell-7.2)

[Save-Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/save-module?view=powershell-7.2)

[Import-Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-7.2)