# Can't use OpenAI in powershell

Tags: python, windows, powershell, openai-api

I installed the OpenAI module on my Windows machine using
`pip install --upgrade openai`.

Now if I try to use `openai` in the shell, it gives me an error:

> openai : The term 'openai' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

`openai` is installed at:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\openai
```

Comment: Can you confirm if you have launched Python 3 interpreter in Powershell before using `openai` package?

Comment: Yes i have been able to launch python3 before using openai

Comment: Can you share the code as well which you have used to import `openai` in the Python session? Please also check if `openai` is accessible to Powershell: [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72840280/7789963).

Comment: I tried to install it and use the openai cli. I installed using ```pip install --upgrade openai``` then ran ```openai --help``` when i ran into the error

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by uninstalling openai and then installing it again. This time I paid attention to the warning at the bottom of install. It clearly says that the scripts folder is not in PATH. I added the folder location to PATH and it worked.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv2rQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, press the windows key, and search for "Edit the system environment variables". Next, press the "Environment Variables..." button. Find the "System variables" section and find the "Path" variable. Click on it and press "Edit...". That should open a new window. In the new window, press on "New" and paste this in it (Without the quotes):

"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\openai"

Now, reopen the command prompt and use the module!

Comment: (This was the explanation on how to add the script to path)